# Backbone event bus, making sure each event is processed only once

Tags: backbone.js

I'm building a project using the Backbone global as an event bus. The idea is that a view will trigger a custom event and pass in some data, then whatever collection is listening for that event will use the data to create a model and add that model to itself, and give some kind of message.

I notice that if I start from a new instance of my application and trigger one of these events, then in Chrome Dev Tools, `Backbone._events` looks something like this: `{'add_person': [Object] }` and the appropriate event handler runs and processes that one object in the value array. So far, so good.

Now, let's say I trigger that event handler again. What I've noticed is that `Backbone._events` looks like `{'add_person': [Object, Object]}` and the event handler runs twice, presumably on both members of the value array, including the first which was already processed.

My question is how do I prevent this behavior, short of binding the event with `once` and re-binding it after each time it's called? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your setup is, i.e. how you're triggering and listening to these events you're firing but it sounds like you might be doing something like:

```
GlobalEventBus.on('add_person', this.addPerson, this);
```

Assuming you're binding to the event using `on` this could well be your problem if you're not manually unbinding the listener when your view is destroyed.

You're better off using Backbone's `listenTo` when listening to events that are triggered from an object **outside** the object you're listening in.

So, for example, in your collection you'd instead have:

```
this.listenTo(GlobalEventBus, 'add_person', this.addPerson)
```

Again though, i'm not entirely sure what your setup is.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYWbyR?editors=101) for a working example.

Only one events is triggered each time but keep in mind that only one model is being added because each model is a duplicate and has the same id. Assuming each model was unique it would be added to the collection.

[Some further info on listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)